# Can You Use URI's from a Library (PicturesLibrary) In UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm trying to use this code to access a file's URI from the PicturesLibrary:

```
    StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

    StorageFile tpkFile = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync("campus.tpk");

    Uri tpkFileUri = new Uri(tpkFile.Path);

    Debug.WriteLine("This is the tpkFile path: " + tpkFileUri);

    ArcGISTiledLayer tpkLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer(tpkFileUri);
    try
    {
        MyMapView.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(tpkLayer);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This is the Exception: " + e);
    }
```

Which returns a URI of:

```
file:///C:/Users/username/Pictures/campus.tpk
```

But I know UWP apps only take URIs that start with `ms-appx:///`

**My question is, how can I can I access the file at the first URI with the ms-appx:/// prefix?**

Right now the code fails at this line:

```
ArcGISTiledLayer tpkLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer(tpkFileUri);
```

Because it says the URI is not correct, so the reference to tpkLayer is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy it to your ApplicationData.Current and use ms-appdata:/// would that work for you? ms-appx:/// reference to the files in your appx which is readonly.

here you can read more about the ms-appdata schema: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/06/19/common-questions-and-answers-about-files-and-app-data-part-1-app-data/#j4m8ylp93K7ujk6Q.97

Comment: Is there no other way, than copying from the library to the AppX/Assets folder?

Comment: Hey Dave, thank you very much for answering so quickly. Just to clarify, is there another library or location outside of the app-data folder that would work? Perhaps another library?